# How to get all filtered data rows in excel (with hidden columns)?

Tags: excel, vba, filter, loops

My data sheet has filters and hidden columns. When filter(s) applies, I need to loop through all filtered data. I use: 
  Excel.Range visibleRange =  this.UsedRange.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible, missing) as Excel.Range;

Now visibleRange.Rows.Count is 0; use foreach loop "foreach(Excel.Range row in visibleRange.Row)"   row doesn't have all the columns, chopped from the first hidden column.

How could we loop through the filtered rows?

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't use the `SpecialCells` property at all. Just iterate through every row in the `UsedRange` and check the `Hidden` property as you go.

Not sure what language you are using but here's an example in VBA:

```
Dim rowIndex As Range

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For Each rowIndex In .UsedRange.Rows
        If (rowIndex.Hidden) Then
            ' do nothing - row is filtered out
        Else
            ' do something
        End If
    Next rowIndex
End With
```

Each row (or rather each `Range` object referenced by `rowIndex`) will contain all of the columns including the hidden ones. If you need to determine whether or not a column is hidden then just check the `Hidden` property but remember that this only applies to entire columns or rows:

```
Dim rowIndex As Range
Dim colNumber As Integer

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For Each rowIndex In .UsedRange.Rows
        If (rowIndex.Hidden) Then
            ' do nothing - row is filtered out
        Else
            For colNumber = 1 To .UsedRange.Columns.Count
                ' Need to check the Columns property of the Worksheet
                ' to ensure we get the entire column
                If (.Columns(colNumber).Hidden) Then
                    ' do something with rowIndex.Cells(1, colNumber)
                Else
                    ' do something else with rowIndex.Cells(1, colNumber)
                End If
            Next colNumber
        End If
    Next rowIndex
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Thread Necro time.  Here's what I do.

```
'Count the total number of used rows in the worksheet (Using Column A to count on)

numFilteredCells = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(3, Range("A1:A" & Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row))

'Find Last filtered row with content

j = Range("A1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Row

'Subtract the total number of filtered rows with content, + 1

jTargetDataRow = j - numFilteredCells + 1
```

`jTargetDataRow` now contains the first filtered row with content, `j` contains the last, and `numFilteredCells` contains the total number of filtered rows that have content.